# iOS app icon background color during zoom-out to home transition animation

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, sketchapp

My app icon that I created in sketch using a template looks fine on my device and in the simulator.

My issue is that when I'm in my app and I click to go home the app zoom out transition animation underneath the app icon is a different color than the app icon and it doesn't look good.

I'm assuming i'm doing something wrong with the app icon design or maybe it's something to do with my app window background color.

Here's a screenshot during the transition and when transition is completed.

***During transition***

[image: during transition]

***Transition complete***

[image: transition complete]

Comment: Have you created *all* the app icon versions you need? It could be device related. If the answer @shayegh gave doesn't help, please update your question with (1) what simulator devices you've tested, (2) what actual devices you've tested, and most importantly (3) what your assets look like.

Comment: @dfd I have created all the icon versions. I used this Sketch app template that exports all the different icon versions that is required for the iPhone. I've tried the pre-rendered option with no luck.

Comment: Hmmm. Thanks for the additional details. I use Sketch to create my app icons also. Let me make sure I understand the issue: (1) The icon looks good on the home screen and (2) looks good *after* the animation *back* to the home screen. It's just that it doesn't look good *during* the animation? The one thing I do differently (and I'm hesitant to recommend this) is I use Sketch to *create* the (1024x1024 png). Then I use a third party product - I believe it's freemium and well supported - called "Asset Catalog Creator" available in the Mac App Store. I checked at my apps and see no problems.

Comment: @dfd I just solved my problem by making square app icons and letting Xcode do the rendering for me. The icon looks fine on my device and simulator.

Comment: Ah. You should post that as an answer to your question. I don't believe I've seen the exact issue and, well, always let iOS do the rendering of a square icon image. This may help others. Post it and I'll up-vote it.

Comment: @dfd I just added that as the answer. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating a square app icon and letting Xcode render the icon for me. I made a 1024x1024 square in Sketch and designed the icon and then exported all the required icon sizes. I imported the icons into the AppIcon set in Xcode. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

set render as to Original Image

[image]

Comment: The only option that I have in my AppIcon set is a checkbox that says "iOS icon is pre-rendered". I selected this and tested the app in the simulator and my device and still experiencing the same problem.